# Is it possible to search for gifs in messages? (Samsung Note 8)

Tags: samsung, sms, keyboard

I am currently using a Samsung Galaxy Note 8, which in the default messaging app has a keyboard option to send a gif image. When selected gifs appear and there are categories at the bottom (Trending, Happy, Fun, etc. etc.) However, I find this to be very ineffective and restrictive to find the actual gifs I want.

I checked on an [Android forum](https://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s9-s9-plus/875499-search-gif-keyboard.html), where some of the responses seem to indicated there is a search function, but this seems to be applicable to the S9 and conflicting information if it *still* exists.

So now I turn here... **Does a search function exist for the gif keyboard, and if so how do I access it?**

<sub>Message version: 4.4.11.4 -- Message Service version 4.4.10.4</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I have not found any function within the Samsung Keyboard to allow for a search, this problem is easily solved by downloading a third-party keyboard...

I chose **[Gboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.latin&hl=en_US).**

I have also heard that [SwiftKey](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.touchtype.swiftkey&hl=en_US) is a popular option.